# Missing response body from RestClientResponseException in Spring REST response

Tags: java, spring, rest, response

In my **Spring Boot REST application** I have an endpoint, where I do some stuff. There I also have a `@Provider`, where I can catch and map all exceptions occurred during the process:

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        ErrorObject error = new ErrorObject("INTERNAL", 500, ex.getMessage());
        return Response.status(error.getStatus()).entity(error).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

The `ErrorObject` is just a basic pojo with some information:

```
public class ErrorObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4181809471936547469L;

    public ErrorObject(String name, int status, String message) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    private String name;
    private int status;
    private String message;

    setters/getters
}
```

If I call my endpoint **with postman**, I got this response if the exception occurs, and this is perfect:

```
{
    "name": "INTERNAL",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "something happened",
}
```

But when I call the endpoint **within my application**, I catch the `RestClientResponseException` (which is basically `HttpClientErrorException`), I can see in the exception that it was 500, but there is no body, it is empty.

This is how I call it within my application:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<WhateverObject> entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, getBaseHeadersAsHttpEntity(), WhateverObject.class);
    //...
} catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
    //... ErrorObject of exception is missing here
}
```

***How can I get the same body in case of exception, so my own ErrorObject from the exception?***

Comment: If you are calling endpoint within your application with `RestTemplate` you need to ovverride DefaultErrorHandler in it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. I tried it, and then I realized that it cannot store the response body in the background, and than I found out that I need to set a new request factory:
`restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment of @Hemant Patel, after trying to set a new ErrorHandler, I figured out that the only thing I need to set is a new request factory:

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

And this factory is able to set the response body in the background successfully.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, but setting the request factory did not resolve the issue. Any more changes required?